# Undefined reference when building qt with cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm having trouble building a project using Qt and VTK. I'm using Cmake 3.5.1, vtk7.1 and Qt5.2.1. When I run make after running cmake I get this error:

> CMakeFiles/MainWindow.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to`MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x12f): undefined reference to `MainWindow::~MainWindow()'
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to`MainWindow::~MainWindow()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   CMakeFiles/MainWindow.dir/build.make:218: recipe for target 'MainWindow' failed
>   make[2]: *** [MainWindow] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MainWindow.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MainWindow.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

My CmakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
if(POLICY CMP0020)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0020 NEW)
endif()
if(POLICY CMP0025)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0025 NEW) # CMake 3.0
endif()
if(POLICY CMP0043)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0043 NEW) # CMake 3.0
endif()
if(POLICY CMP0053)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0053 NEW) # CMake 3.1
endif()
project(MainWindow)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

if("${VTK_QT_VERSION}" STREQUAL "")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "VTK was not built with Qt")
endif()

set( Srcs main.cpp )

if(VTK_QT_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "4")
  find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED QUIET)

  add_executable(MainWindow ${Srcs})
  qt5_use_modules(MainWindow Core Gui Widgets)
  target_link_libraries(MainWindow ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
  include(${QT_USE_FILE})
  # Use what VTK built with
  set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  set(QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  set(QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE ${VTK_QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE} CACHE FILEPATH "")
  include_directories(${QT_INCLUDE_DIR})

  add_executable(MainWindow ${Srcs})
  target_link_libraries(MainWindow ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

The error seems to be associated with the cons and ~cons. Here is a snippet from the MainWindow cpp where I think the problem is arising:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow){    

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    writeSettings();
    axes->Delete();
    marker->Delete();
    delete ui;
}
```

and here is some of the header:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    /*signals:
    void overVolume(int, int, int);*/
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
```

I exclude the body of the constructor because it is very long and I don't think it has anything to do with the error.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to update your `Srcs` variable to include *all* necessary cpp files to build the `MainWindow` target (executable).

As a result you omit the code for implementing the `MainWindow` class entirely in the `add_executable(MainWindow ${Srcs})` statement. That has the side-effect that the linker sees only function calls to `MainWindow` from your `main.cpp` which probably amount to just creating one and (implicitly) destroying one, hence the linker complaining about these exact 2 functions being undefined.

So, to fix all this, expand your definition of `${Srcs}` in `set( Srcs main.cpp )` with something like this:

```
# assuming MainWindow is implemented in mainwindow.cpp
set( Srcs main.cpp mainwindow.cpp)
```